# How to determine if a location.hash change from back button or otherwise

Tags: javascript, mobile, history, transition, back

I'm making a webapp using a history plugin that maps url-fragments like mysite.com/#news to views. It's a mobile HTML5 JavaScript app and when going from mysite.com/#news to mysite.com/#stuff there is a nice sliding right-to-left animation between the pages. All good.

Then the user clicks the browsers "back" button and the location changes back to /#news and the expected transition would be left-to-right. But how can I know that "back" was clicked as opposed to "forward" or some link clicked?

The history plugin just polls for a hash change - it has no idea what caused it. I can't find any useful native event to bind to and security blocks access to the window.history array.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would on each page store what page I was on and what page I came from in a cookie or storage and then see what is the previous page I was on. I.e. keep my own history within my site. This could be combined with the elusive document.referrer to see if I came to a page without referrer, which might be a sign I had used a bookmark

Comment: I was considering something like that too. If you anticipate several back/forward it could get real messy though.
For now I've just made a "fade" animation for when I don't know the direction.